# Making wider rectangles from continuous fixed size rectangles?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I am working on adding Tile collision to my game.

What I do is, I go through each object and get the edge tiles around them.

I return a vector of Vec2 which corresponds  to the top left position of each surrounding edge tile.

Those get put into a set of Vec2 so only unique ones stay.

From there, fixed size rectangles can be constructed.

[image]

However, I require that the contiguous rectangles be merged into 1.

So in this example, we would turn these 8 fixed rectangles into 3.

The rightmost one would stay as is.

The 6 on the x axis would become 1 and the leftmost on the x axis and the one below it would become 1.

Given that I have a set Vec2 denoting the top left position of each tile square and I know the width of the square, how could I compute a new vector of Rectangle(x,y,w,h) with the merged fixed squares?

```
    void TilePhysicsManager::update()
        {
            m_locationSet.clear(); //clear the unique locations

            for (b2Body* b = m_b2world->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext())
            {
                if(b->GetType() == b2_dynamicBody)
                {
                    PhysicsObject* obj = (PhysicsObject*)b->GetUserData();
                    const std::vector<Vec2>& edgeTiles = m_tileWorld->getSideTiles(*obj,1.5f);

                    //add in locations (duplicates will be rejected)
                    for(int i = 0; i < edgeTiles.size(); ++i)
                    {
                        m_locationSet.insert(edgeTiles[i]);
                    }

                }
            }

            int objIndex = 0; //index of which dummy object we need

            for(std::set<Vec2>::iterator it = m_locationSet.begin(); it != m_locationSet.end(); ++it)
            {
                //if our memory pool is not big enough, grow it
                if(objIndex >= count())
                {
                    allocNewObject();
                }

                m_objects[objIndex]->setLocation(*it);
                objIndex++;
            }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Does those continuous fixed rectangle always almost nearly connected? Are you required to produce the minimal wider rectangle from those smaller rectangle or sometimes close to minimal number of wider rectangle is also acceptable?

Comment: @invisal it has to be the longest continuous strips otherwise the player gets stuck on their edges.

Comment: longest vertical continuous strip or longest horizontal continuous strip? which one?

Comment: @invisal it needs to produce both of them, but they are edge tiles so you will only ever have at most L shapes of sorts that produce a vertical and horizontal one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the easiest and also fast way to do this is to do "horizontal continuous strip" expansion following by "vertical continuous strip" expansion or vise versa.

For example:

- Compute the bound rectangle. The number of vertical strip is the height divided by the height of the fixed rectangle.
- Create an array of number of strip elements. That store the min and max X-coordination of the each strip. Use the min and max coordination to construct wider rectangles.

[image]
[image]

- Then, apply the horizontal strip expansion. (in our example, we will have 4 rectangles after the vertical strip expansion).

[image]
[image]

- Create an array of number of strip elements. That store the min and max Y-coordination of the each strip. Use the min and max coordination to construct wider rectangles.
- Check if the wider vertical strip can be further expanse, if yes, expanse.

**Conclusion:**

- This algorithm assumes that there is be no discontinuity in each strip.

**Implementation**

- The following is the optimized implementation in C#

  ```
  private List<Rectangle> Merge(Rectangle[] r) {
      // Computing the bound
      Rectangle bound = new Rectangle(r[0].X, r[0].Y, r[0].Width, r[0].Height);
      for (int i = 1; i < r.Length; ++i) {
          bound.X = Math.Min(bound.X, r[i].X);
          bound.Y = Math.Min(bound.Y, r[i].Y);
          bound.Width = Math.Max(bound.Right, r[i].Right) - bound.X;
          bound.Height = Math.Max(bound.Bottom, r[i].Bottom) - bound.Y;
      }

      // Create number of rectangle will be created by vertical strip expansion
      Rectangle[] m = new Rectangle[bound.Height / RECT_HEIGHT];
      for (int i = 0; i < m.Length; ++i) {
          m[i] = new Rectangle(Int32.MaxValue, bound.Y +  i * RECT_HEIGHT, 0, RECT_HEIGHT);
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < r.Length; ++i) {
          int index = (r[i].Y - bound.Y) / RECT_HEIGHT;

          if (m[index].Width <= 0) {
              m[index].Width = r[i].Width;
              m[index].X = r[i].X;
          } else {
              int right = m[index].Right;
              m[index].X = Math.Min(m[index].X, r[i].X);
              m[index].Width = Math.Max(right, r[i].Right) - m[index].X;
          }
      }

      // Merge horozontally
      for (int i = m.Length - 1; i > 0; --i) {
          // can only merge when two rect has the same X and Width
          if ((m[i].X == m[i - 1].X) && (m[i].Width == m[i - 1].Width)) {
              m[i - 1].Height += m[i].Height; // expanse the rectangle
              m[i].Width = 0;                // remove one rectangle
          }
      }

      // Remove all the empty rectangle
      List<Rectangle> result = new List<Rectangle>();
      for (int i = m.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
          if (m[i].Width > 0)
              result.Add(m[i]);
      }

      return result;
  }
  ```

The following are result generating by the following implementation. The left side is the initial rectangles, and the right side is the result.

- Create a bigger rectangle if two vertical box can be merged.

[image]

- Prioritize the vertical box over horizontal box

[image]

- There is discontinue space between two box in one vertical strip. The result is not what we expect it should be.

[image]

Comment: Is there any way that, in the case you showed a picture for, that the vertical one extends and intersects the horizontal one (its top coordinate would be extended by 1 square) otherwise I get the same issue, just less often. Thanks

Comment: I don't get your question. What the algorithm guarantee is that it will return the wider rectangles with no any intersection among them. Since, we first extends vertical first, then extends horizontal later if it is extendable. How do we know if two rectangles can horizontally merge together? We can check if those two have equal width and left position. If you look at the last picture, the lower rectangle cannot merge with middle rectangle because they have different width.

Comment: @Milo, like in my post, this algorithm make an assumption that there is no discontinuity in each vertical strip. If you carefully examine the implementation, you will see why.

Comment: Well, once the rectangles are all made you could do:

for each vertical box
for each horizontal box
if vertical.topleft == horizontal.bottomleft
extend vertical upward by horizontal's height

Comment: @Milo, I have updated the implementation and added more demo images.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem statement has a little ambiguity to resolve.  In the example given, there are multiple possible ways to group the given tiles into maximal, nonoverlapping larger rectangles.  Specifically, the top left corner tile could be merged with the rest of the row as you suggest, or it could be merged with the one below it.

As far as an algorithm, what first occurs to me is to take tiles from the set one by one and expand them via their neighbors.  When expanding a rectangle of more than one tile, simply check that all the tiles on that edge have a neighbor in (what remains of) the individual set.  Once you find that the rectangle cannot expand in any direction, you're done and can move on to the next tile.

This approach seems about O(n^2) to me, which could probably be improved upon but could easily be a non-issue in practice, depending on the scale and how often you need to evaluate this (with static level geometry, not very often I'd hope).

One thing to be wary of with an approach like this is not to make the mistake of removing elements from a container while iterating over it.  Bad iterator juju.  Just make a copy.

Comment: I unfortunately need to compute this every frame.

Comment: Still might be fine.  Really depends on how big n gets.

Okay, though, let's say we want to make it faster.  Well, the first thing I thought of was actually to go through and bucketize the tiles by their y coordinate.  Then, within each bucket (sorted by x), do a linear scan to find contiguous strips.  Perhaps those strips, even if not vertically maximal, would suffice for your purposes?

If not, it shouldn't be too much additional work to identify neighboring strips that can be merged.  Just sort the strips by their leftmost x coordinate and scan right, combining neighbors as you find them.